# Rolling policy in logback is don't like what I want

Tags: java, policy, appender

I have a problem when using **logback** to write log file daily (when a new day has been started,  **logback** compress the file to zip file).

When I set the time is end of day, and run **logback**, it still run normally.
But when the day has been **changed**, and **logback** was **running**...the old day log file still exist, and the zip file of old date and the new date log file have been created.

I want when the new day come, the old log file compress to zip file and new day log file is created.

Show me your ideas, please!
thanks for your help.

Here is my logback.xml config file:

```xml
<appender name="RollByTimeComp"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>c:/day-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.zip
        </fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5p] %m \(%F:%L\) %C:%M\(\)%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: lockback? I assume you mean logback?

Comment: sorry for my mistake..